# Комментарий с требованием ответа, что это - наивность?

Tags: обсуждение

Собственно, это скорее не вопрос, а приглашение к осмыслению. Специально сделал скриншот комментария из вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1278379/195342

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть, стоит написать очень большими буквами на самой первой странице, что ruSO - не сайт по решению чужих задач?

Может, этот комментарий и яйца выеденного не стоит, но очень захотелось поделиться этим перлом. Или я не понял какого-то скрытого сарказма? :)

P.S. Интересное замечание в тему попалось...

> младшие сотрудники (джуны) совершали больше ошибок и чаще обращались за разъяснениями к более опытным коллегам за помощью. Часто доходило до крайностей — вопросы возникали такие, которые можно было нагуглить за 1-2 минуты, а ответ было в первых пяти ссылках на первой странице поисковика.
> Время шло, ранние джуны получали опыт, знания, возмужали и перешли из ждуна в мидла. Но, увы картина не менялась — они никак не хотели принимать тот факт, что ответ они могут найти сами. Все так же шли с вопросами к более опытным товарищам за разъяснениями.
> Интересен тот факт, что подобное поведение заметил не только я, но и ряд мои коллег, которые примерно одно возраста со мной.

[Отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/557182/)

Comment: Если так часто делать чужие домашки, что не мудрено, что это будет вменяться в обязанность ;-)

Comment: Да, это апофеоз...

Comment: Цитатный чат ;)

Comment: Еще одна особенность социокультурной адаптации нового поколения в условиях современного мира. Harry, вы в глазах современной молодежи как Алиса от Яндекса, только умнее и безотказнее. Алиса в некоторых ситуациях может послать... по ссылке, а вы мишка такой на вид плюшевый и безотказный, и вами можно манипулировать. У вас только два варианта на выбор - или беспрекословно исполнять все команды, или мишку заменить на типичную физиономию грозного преподавателя :))

Comment: @Sevastopol' Вот уж о чем никогда не задумывался, так это об аватаре... Такой намек, как вы считаете, более понятен? :)

Comment: Главное, не появляйтесь с такой аватаркой в англоязычном сегменте SE — могут забанить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ За что?! За фотоаппарат?! Если уж за косяк не банили... :)

Comment: Вот ссылочка на [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=41858142#41858142). За расположение. А вы активно участвовали на enSO с косяком? С другой стороны - траву же там легализовали уже.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ну точно "это вы, доктор, такие картинки показываете!"... :)

Comment: @Harry, это была шутка. К тому же, `Harry` и `мишка с соской` это уже бренд ruSO. Думаю, не стоило менять. Потому что теперь, с такой новой аватаркой, страшно представить, что с вами будет :)

Comment: @Sevastopol' Ладно, верну. Самому нравится :) Только присмотритесь - это не соска, а сигаретка :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у меня на аватарке Шерлока Холмса, вообще курительная трубка. И здесь и на EnSO не заметил особого дискомфорта по этой причине. Правда периодически её заменяю, когда самому надоедает.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT повторюсь ещё раз. Дело не в трубке/сигаретке/фотоаппарате/etc ... а в месте приложения оного к основному субъекту на аватарке. Опусти ниже пояса и ты уже кандидат на блокировку, если заметит кто-то чуФствительный, как-то так.

Comment: @Harry, а я почему-то всегда думал, что это соска)) Не всматривался. Теперь будем знать, что Шерлок и Мишка у нас дымят на пару :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а-а понятно, видимо не всё, и не везде прочитал. Правда юмор ниже пояса, на мой взгляд, всё таки ближе Enso. В качестве примера наибольшей популярностью пользуются анимашки с наклоном и показом голой задницы, как правило такие набирают наибольшее число голосов.  Или к примеру концерты AC/DC публика заходится в экстазе, когда солист наклоняется и показывает задницу.

Comment: @Sevastopol' "особенность социокультурной адаптации" - слишком длинные слова. Это называется гораздо проще - жлобство.

Comment: Да, часто пишут: "Мне надо...", "Надо решить ..." причем нет своих попыток вообще или код не свой откуда-нибудь скопируют.

Comment: Раньше на программировании чертили на доске, некоторые лицезрели чудо компы 70-х 80-х на которых иногда даже небыло возможности сохранить программу, или были ещё всякие интересные неудобства. Помню один дисковод на всех, или кто-то поставил две дискеты в дисковод. Народ играл в игры, а оценку ставили за присутствие на уроке. А теперь это учат, это модно, и возможно некоторых заставляют учить, и к тому же прильщает возможность списать, ведь почерк не видно)))

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну, я помню перфокарты и перфоленты... но не вижу связи.

Answer (score 24):

Возможно, это индикатор того, что не нужно решать задачи для каждого первого (или всё же второго?) встречного студента с плохосформулированной постановкой. Даже если задача вам интересна, даже если на это у вас есть время, даже если можно поднять ещё немного репы...

Я могу, конечно, ошибаться, но допускаю, что в данном случае у конкретного участника о вас просто уже сложилось мнение безотказного "решалы" и он откровенно недоумевает - "а где же ответ? почему его так долго нет? ведь для него этот вопрос проще пареной репы".

Comment: Возможно. Но (особенно с этими локдаунами...) по сути ФБ и ruSO - у меня две возможности утоления жажды общения, как бы выспренно это ни звучало. Ничего, в июне надеюсь все же сорваться в отпуск, и тогда... :)

Comment: Ну вот, весь день - только соберусь ответить - ан нет, сам себя по рукам - не надо задачи решать ни для первого, ни для второго... На третьем сбиваюсь со счета, и все по новой... :)

Comment: Надо давать имя переменной so или vso или _so - если тупо спишут - училка поржёт)))

Comment: Честно говоря, я сам порой грешу такими сообщениями. Могу предположить из собственного опыта, что они вызваны не наглостью, а нехваткой коммуникативных навыков, перфекционизмом, общественными стереотипами и представлениями об уникальности своего кода. Как джуниор, я еще подпадаю под влияние последнего

Comment: Можно ещё отметить неопытность в программировании вообщем